# Data and time in Form react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

Using react-bootstrap, have a form which displays some fields, one field is the date.

```
<Form onSubmit={...}>
  <Form.Row >
      <Form.Group>
      ...
      </Form.Group>
  </Form.Row >
  <Form.Row >
      <Form.Group>
      <Form.Control type="date" name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
      </Form.Group>
  </Form.Row >
  <Form.Row >
      <Form.Group>
      ...
      </Form.Group>
  </Form.Row >
</Form>
```

2nd Row in the Form, using the Form.Contol type as **Date**, through this I can only select the Date, is there a way to select the time in Form?  or any other **react-bootstrap components** which can be used to select both **Date and Time**?

Comment: You can try [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-times).